# Chaining functions in javascript inside revealing module pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to improve my javascript and make it more modular, but I'm struggling to get my head around to make the following functions 'chainable'.

```
var message = {
    send: function send(query) {            
        $(".spinner").css({ display: "block" });
        queryAda(query)
        .done(function (result) {
            console.log("success", result);
            var message = cleanAda(result);
            console.log(message);
            storage.save();
            return this;
        })
        .fail(function (xhr) {
            console.log("error", xhr);
            var message = "I'm sorry, but there was an error and I couldn't retrieve your request. Please try again.";
            return this;
        });
        return {
            query: query,
            message: message,
        };
    }
};

var display = {
    remove: function remove() {
        $(".ADA-BUBBLE").removeClass("SHOW");
        $(".ADA-EXAMPLES li").removeClass("SHOW");
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".ADA-EXAMPLES").css({ display: "none" });
        }, 500);
    },
    show: function show(input, output) {
        $("#ADA-Q-TXT").text(input);
        $(".ADA-BUBBLE").css({ "margin-bottom": "112px" });
        $(".spinner").css({ display: "none" });
        $(".ADA-BUBBLE").html(output);
        styleTable();
        setTimeout(function () {
            $(".ADA-BUBBLE").addClass("SHOW");
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

I'm using them in a revealing module pattern named moduleAda.

I'd like to be able to use them like:

```
moduleAda.message.send("hello").display.show()
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50326017/chaining-functions-in-javascript-inside-revealing-module-pattern

Comment: Well, `send()` needs to return an object that has a property called `display`. Also, how are you publishing `message` within the module? Are you using ES6 modules, or CommonJS, or Require...?

Comment: @HelloWorld why do you ask OP to check back this exact same question?